# split() in Classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a one String in classic asp.

```
Dim str 
str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/code-classic-asp-in-linux"
```

In above string, I want text after "code" by using split() in Classic asp.

Result should be: **"-classic-asp-in-linux"**

Comment: I think that `IndexOf` would be better than `Split()`

Comment: can you give the syntax for IndexOf() by using above string as example.

Comment: @ User: Do you use JScript or VBscript as programming language?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neil is right. But in VBScript `IndexOf` equivalent is `InStr`.

```vb
Dim str 
str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/code-classic-asp-in-linux"

'Split
Response.Write Split(str,"-", 2)(1) ' classic-asp-in-linux
'Mid & InStr
Response.Write Mid(str, InStr(str, "-")) ' -classic-asp-in-linux
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a really old post, I know, but maybe somebody will find this useful... I perceive the OP's actual question to be "how do I get the doc name from the end of a URL?" The answer is to get everything *after the last slash*. Here I use InStrRev to find the last slash, store it's position and then use the Right function to capture the end of the url.

```
Dim str, tmp
str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/code-classic-asp-in-linux"
tmp = InStrRev(str, "/")
str = Right(str, Len(str) - tmp)
Response.write str
```

If the URL has a trailing slash on it, that would cause a problem, so in usage, you'd want to check for that possibility.

Comment: Not answer to the question and a wrong answer to the imagined problem (you should use FSO methods (e.g. .GetFileName()) to work with file specs).

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this:

```
Dim str, arrSplitted
str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/code-classic-asp-in-linux"
arrSplitted = Split(str, "code-")
```

arrSplitted will return an array which contains two nodes, 0 and 1. Node 1 should contain -classic-as-in-linux.

```
Response.Write arrSplitted(1)
```

Hope it works, it was a few years ago I used classic ASP.

Comment: This works, but only in the given example. I guess the OP needs a general solution

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim str, arrSplitted, tmp
str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/code-classic-asp-in-linux"
tmp = split(str, "code")
Response.Write(tmp(UBound(tmp))) 'return the last element of the array.
```

Also you can use Response.Write(split(str, "code")(UBound(split(str, "code")))) but the split is executed twice, that is why used 'tmp' variable.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative.
If your URL scheme is fixed, then you can simply replace the fixed part to nothing.

```
Dim str 
str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/code-classic-asp-in-linux"
str = Replace(str,"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/code-","")
Response.write str
```